# MySQL NULL Value query Issue

Tags: mysql

Can any one guess what is teh issue in attached screen shot?

[image]

Comment: Not me site cannot be reached. Best add to the question in some other way.

Comment: Please paste or retype the error message in your question. Also provide the steps or circumstances leading to the error. Apart from being rude to those who wish to help you, the external link does not load.

Comment: can you click 2 hyper link for image

Comment: You `TRIM` on the wrong side of `=`. And you have a line break in your data.

Comment: @user2629839 post the *text*, not links or images. Images can't be executed. Don't force people to try to read that image and retype the query when you can simply copy the text

Comment: BTW that screenshot doesn't show any nulls. It shows there are no results because the second query just checks whether a field is *equal* to a string

Comment: Wow.. Who approved **teh** edit? Don't people read what they approave?

Comment: we are  getting Empty , but table have that entry.

Comment: Did you read @Paul Spiegel comment?

Answer (score 0):

Your first query works because you just used the `LIKE` clause with trailing `%`. For later case you just used the `TRIM` on the static text not on the value of your table column called`Vs_Info`. So you can try this way with [TRIM()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_trim)

```
SELECT Vs_Info FROM tbl_lb_dtls WHERE TRIM(Vs_Info) = 'shr-php-s-ame_eltkeynote-9185-vip';
```